# Horizontal scrolling using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I use the arctic scroll plugin to scroll smoothly to a div whenever needed, but that works only when you have vertical divs.
I want to do that to a horizontal arrangement of divs which I don't even know how to make. Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: @AnujKaithwas -- due to the nature of how Stack Overflow works, it is often impossible to any kind of useful advice without seeing the *context*, that is to say the *code* around a question.  In addition, most people here on Stack Overflow will be more than willing to help resolve a specific coding/programming problem, but won't provide help if the question doesn't show some attempt to solve the problem on their own.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher With all due respect Sir, I totally understand what you want to tell me. Some people however do not feel that way. I have mentioned in the question itself that I have no idea how to code that thing. So how can anyone expect  a snippet? Should I give them the code that has 3 div tags with classes assigned to each?

Answer (score 0):

[Plugin source](http://jsbin.com/izocuz)
we can see here that it uses only top coordinates, you can modify source code, change **scrollTop** to **scrollLeft**